# Why bolding a specific characters of a string does not render <b> element in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I wanna bold a specific part of a string in my react js app but the result is not true;
This is my code and its returned:

```js
data?.map((item) => (<li key={item.id}>{item.title.replace(new RegExp(value, 'g'), `<b>${value}</b>`)}</li>)) // rendered value: app<b>l</b>e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're returning a string, not a react element. That is to say, There's an important difference between `app<b>l</b>e` (an array of react elements) and `'app<b>l</b>e'` (a string).

```
data?.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
      {
        // spread to convert string to array
        [...item.title].map((letter) =>
          // if the letter matches, wrap in a <b/> tag
          letter === value ? <b>{letter}</b> : letter)
      }
      </li>
    ))
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-tree-r4egc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm writing a autocomplete search so the specific part can be any characters that mean is dynamic so what can I do for this situation?

Comment: You could definitely come up with something clever by splitting the matching portion out of the title and wrapping it. The alternative would be to use your original code with [`dangerouslySetInnerHtml`](https://linguinecode.com/post/complete-guide-react-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)